# jQuery get checked radio on unique form ID

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to get the value of a radio named *bookID* in a form with a unique ID, like:

```
form id="f-uniqueID"
```

(There are multiple forms with the same fields on one page.)

added:

```
<form id='f-uniqueID'>
<li><input type='radio' name='bookID' value='$bookID' class='bookID_select'><span  class='vidBk_select_click'> $book_title</span></li>
<li><input type='radio' name='bookID' value='$bookID' class='bookID_select'><span  class='vidBk_select_click'> $book_title</span></li>
<li><input type='radio' name='bookID' value='$bookID' class='bookID_select'><span  class='vidBk_select_click'> $book_title</span></li>
</form>
```

I've tried all the variations on this one, including others I found here, but nothing seems to work.

```
var bookNR = $("#f-"+uniqueID+" input[name='bookID']:checked").val();
```

Does anyone know how to get the bookNR value? I keeps alerting me as *undefined*.

Comment: paste your html code structure

Comment: Provide a **runnable** [mcve] that reproduces issue. There simply isn't enough detail provided to help you

Comment: that is actually the form ID I posted at first. There are multiple forms with different ID's. The bookID's though, are all the same so I want to find the checked radio for each formID.

Comment: [This method works fine](https://jsfiddle.net/3j2q10qc/1/). Your doing something wrong.

Comment: added code to the question

Comment: Not enough. We have no idea what `uniqueID` is and the values seem like they are some sort of server side variable. And you don't show where you call this code

Comment: [Example with your code](https://jsfiddle.net/3j2q10qc/2/). I'm guessing your calling this before any of them are checked?

Answer (score -1):

Kindly check the following code:-

```
<form id='f-uniqueID'>
<li><input type='radio' name='bookID' value='$bookID' class='bookID_select'><span  class='vidBk_select_click'> $book_title</span></li>
<li><input type='radio' name='bookID' value='$bookID' class='bookID_select'><span  class='vidBk_select_click'> $book_title</span></li>
<li><input type='radio' name='bookID' value='$bookID' class='bookID_select'><span  class='vidBk_select_click'> $book_title</span></li>
</form>
```

Here all values attribute contain same value as $bookID, If we have all the different radio inputs of given same name contains similar value, then jquery selector returns 'undefined'. Use different value for each radio value attribute.